# Usage of fwrite()

Tags: c

```
unsigned char data_packet[72] =
{
            0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xB2, 0x47, 0x41, 0x39, 0x34, 0x03, 0xD4, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x31, 0x32, 0xFD, 0x80,
            0x80, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00,
            0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA,
            0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00,
            0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF
};
```

I have this packet of data and I want to write it to a binary file using `fwrite()` function. How can I achieve it in *C* language?

Comment: Look up the documentation for `fwrite` , `fopen` and `fclose`. If you can't get it working then post what you tried and what problem it had

Answer (score 1):

A simple:

```
size_t elementsWritten = fwrite( data_packet, sizeof (data_packet),
    1, fileHandle);
```

should do the trick.

The parameters to `fwrite` are:

- the buffer address.
- the size of an "element".
- the number of elements to write.
- the file handle to use (e.g., from `fopen()`).

It will return the number of elements that were successfully written which, in this case, should be one.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to decode the binary file I have now and print it on the console, using fread()

Comment: @user3689964, that would be a _different_ question so I suspect the best approach would be to ask a different question :-) Seriously, you'll get a much wider response that way. As a hint, if you use fread to read it back in (and the parameters are _very_ similar), you can then use `printf` with the `%x` format specifier to print the individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS CODE, Which creates sample.bin file in the directory from where you're executing the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int counter;
    FILE *ptr;

    unsigned char data_packet[72] =
    {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xB2, 0x47, 0x41, 0x39, 0x34, 0x03, 0xD4, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0x31, 0x32, 0xFD, 0x80,
        0x80, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00,
        0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA,
        0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00,
        0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF
    };

    ptr=fopen("test.bin","wb");
    if (!ptr)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file!");
        return 1;
    }
    fwrite(data_packet, sizeof(data_packet[0]), sizeof(data_packet)/sizeof(data_packet[0]), ptr);
    fclose(ptr);
    printf("succes");
    getch();//return 0;
}
```